# T-SQL: Slow performance on Stored Procedure Sending Data to LinkedServers

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am new to T-SQL and I am facing an issue with a slow processing stored procedure. The purpose of this procedure is to transfer table data from child databases up to their corresponding parents.

The procedure does this by recursively calling the below listed procedure on the child databases found on other linkedservers (via another procedure called 'RunProcedureOnChildren') and once it reaches the last child it will then get the parent database (via the 'GetParentDatabase' procedure) of that child and push the data upwards.

For the purposes of this question; we will assume that the 'RunProcedureOnChildren' and 'GetParentDatabase' procedures are already being efficient.

Table data Info:

- Over 30,000 rows
- Primary Key - TestID (int) - Clustered Index
- Identity Specification - Yes
- Columns - TestID (int), Color (int), ExportedOn (datetime)
- Both source and target tables are the exact same; data may vary inside

[Plan Execution](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1bioPIlo)

[image]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SendSchema].[TransferMyTable]
AS
BEGIN
    --Step 1: Instruct Children to export their Data up. (recursive call)
    Exec [SendSchema].[RunProcedureOnChildren] '[SendSchema].[TransferMyTable]'

    --Step 2: Get the parent database we'll be sending data to.
    Declare @ParentServer varchar(50), @ParentDatabaseName varchar(50);

    Exec [SendSchema].[GetParentDatabase] @ParentDatabaseName Output, @ParentServer Output

    If @ParentDatabaseName != '' AND @ParentServer != '' OR @ParentDatabaseName IS NOT NULL AND @ParentServer IS NOT NULL Begin
        --Step 3: Get the current export time.
        Declare @ExportedOn datetime;
        Set @ExportedOn = GetDate();

        --Step 4: Update new records to have the current export time.
        Update Top(1000) [Schema].[MyTable] Set [ExportedOn] = @ExportedOn
        From [Schema].[MyTable]
        Where [ExportedOn] is null

        --Step 5: Insert those records into the remote server.
        Declare @TSQL varchar(1500);
        Set @TSQL = 'Insert Into [' + @ParentServer + '].[' + @ParentDatabaseName + '].[Schema].[MyTable] ([Color], [ExportedOn])
                    Select [Color], null From [Schema].[MyTable] 
                    Where [ExportedOn] = ''' + Convert(varchar(25), @ExportedOn, 121) + '''
                    ';
        Exec(@TSQL);
    End
END
```

RunProcedureOnChildren

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SendSchema].[RunProcedureOnChildren] 
    @StoredProcedureName varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --Step 1: Remove any old temp tables. This is primarily incase the system fails, that we're not trying to add duplicate records to the temp tables.
    If Object_Id('tempdb..#ChildDatabases') Is Not Null Drop Table #ChildDatabases

    --Step 2: Get the child databases.
    Create Table #ChildDatabases
    (
        [RowNumber] int,
        [ChildDatabaseName] varchar(50),
        [ChildServer] varchar(50),
        [ParentServer] varchar(50)
    )

    Insert Into #ChildDatabases Exec [SendSchema].[GetChildDatabase];

    --Step 3: Execute the Import Data stored procedure on the child databases.
    Declare @RowCount int, @CurrentRow int, @ChildDatabaseName varchar(50), @ChildServer varchar(50);

    Select @RowCount = Count(*) From #ChildDatabases;
    If @RowCount = 0 Begin
        Return
    End
    Set @CurrentRow = 1;

    Declare @OpenQueryTSQL varchar(1500), @TSQL varchar(1500);

    While @CurrentRow <= @RowCount
    Begin
        Select @ChildDatabaseName = [ChildDatabaseName], @ChildServer = [ChildServer]
        From #ChildDatabases
        Where [RowNumber] = @CurrentRow

        Set @TSQL = 'Exec [' + @ChildServer + '].[' + @ChildDatabaseName + '].' + @StoredProcedureName
        Exec (@TSQL)

        Set @CurrentRow += 1
    End

    --Step 4: Clean up the temp tables.
    If Object_Id('tempdb..#ChildDatabases') is not null Drop Table #ChildDatabases
END
```

GetParentDatabase

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SendSchema].[GetParentDatabase]
    @ParentDatabaseName varchar(50) = '' OUTPUT,
    @ParentServer varchar(50) = '' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @ServerName varchar(50), @DatabaseName varchar(50), @DatabaseID int;

    Set @ServerName = @@SERVERNAME
    Set @DatabaseName =  DB_NAME()
    
    Select @DatabaseID = [DatabaseID]
    From [Schema].[Database] DB
    Left Join [Schema].[Server] S ON DB.[ServerID] = S.ServerID
    Where DB.[DatabaseName] = @DatabaseName AND S.[ServerName] = @ServerName

    Declare @ParentDatabaseID int;

    Select @ParentDatabaseID = [ParentDatabaseID],
           @ParentServer = [ParentServer ]
    From [Schema].[Mapper]
    Where [DatabaseID] = @DatabaseID

    Select @ParentDatabaseName = [DatabaseName] 
    From [Schema].[Database]
    Where [DatabaseID] = @ParentDatabaseID

    Return
END
```

GetChildDatabase

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SendSchema].[GetChildDatabase]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @ServerName varchar(50), @DatabaseName varchar(50), @DatabaseID int;

    Set @ServerName = @@SERVERNAME
    Set @DatabaseName =  DB_NAME()
    
    Select @DatabaseID = [DatabaseID]
    From [Schema].[Database] DB
    Left Join [Schema].[Server] S ON DB.[ServerID] = S.ServerID
    Where DB.[DatabaseName] = @DatabaseName AND S.[ServerName] = @ServerName

    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By DB.[DatabaseName] asc) as [RowNumber], DB.[DatabaseName] as [ChildDatabaseName], DBM.[ChildServer], DBM.[ParentServer]
    From [Schema].[Mapper] DBM
    Left Join [Schema].[Database] DB ON DBM.[DatabaseID] = DB.[DatabaseID]
    Where DBM.[ParentDatabaseID] = @DatabaseID


END
```

I've researched a bit and found some suggestions, but I am not sure if they would even help in my case.

1. Insert in batches - based off SQL; it looks like only 1000 rows are being inserted
2. Drop indexes and Recreate Indexes

I would appreciate any suggestions and explanations of where the possible performance issues are and how to fix them. For any solutions please provide explanation and possible documentation.

Hopefully, my question is clear and provided information are clear. If I need to change/update anything please let me know as well.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: So which procedure is slow and can you please provide the actual execution plan for it?

Comment: @J.D. To me it seems the first procedure  'TransferMyTable' is slow; I assume because its sending data to a remote server via a linked server.

Initially 'Exec [SendSchema].[TransferMyTable]' is called to send the data upwards, this recursively calls 'Exec [SendSchema].[RunProcedureOnChildren]' where it gets the children databases and calls '[SendSchema].[TransferMyTable]' procedure on them until it gets to a child with now children

Comment: I'd recommend running each procedure one by one to determine where the slowdown is. Linked Servers aren't necessarily the fastest way to move data, but I wouldn't assume that's your bottleneck either. Then grab the [actual execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16) of the slow procedure and upload it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link it in your original post. That's how we can help you determine what your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Also knowing the total runtime and how many databases this runs over, would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @J.D. The database doesn't have permission to run the execution plan; and I would have to get approval to do it; I can try to get it. Total runtime is around 4-5 minutes and runs over 4 databases/servers. Running procedure over just one server is instant; but 4 at the same time is bogged down.

Comment: It's a permission that's provisioned to a Login or User (not database). You would need `VIEW SERVER STATE` granted to you to be able to see execution plans. It's a rather benign permission and generally there's little reason for a database developer to not have access to it. Otherwise you'll need someone else with a higher privileged account to run the procedure with the actual execution plan enabled.

Comment: @J.D. I've added the execution plan; but from looking at it when I run the "TransferMyTable" procedure it doesn't look like its calling everything; am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139051/discussion-between-j-d-and-drees).